# How to fire "onload" event on document in IE

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, internet-explorer, events, document

I am currently developing Unit Tests for a Javascript method that detects the readiness of the document. This code is already at framework level, so please avoid mentions of this being already implemented in jQuery or another library.

I have successfully simulated the 'readystatechange' change event with the following code:

```
var event;
event = document.createEventObject();
event.type = 'readystatechange';
document.fireEvent('onreadystatechange',event);
```

I failed to do the same for the 'load' event. The following code results in an invalid argument error in IE7, thrown by the call to fireEvent on the last line:

```
event = document.createEventObject();
event.type = 'load';
document.fireEvent('onload',event);
```

Has anyone done this, or failed to do this before? I am also interested in any suggestion to fire the event in a different way.

**Edit:** following the suggestion by Crescent Fresh, I changed my code to:

```
event = document.createEventObject();
event.type = 'load';
document.body.fireEvent('onload',event);
```

There is no more error, but the listener for 'onload' does not fire. Here is how I configured it:

```
document.attachEvent('onload',listener);
```

Comment: The `load` event actually fires on `document.body`. So you can try instead `document.body.fireEvent('onload',event)`. I doubt that'll actually fire handles attached to `onload` though. If it did I'd be shocked....

Comment: You are 100% right. Firing the event on document.body can be done without error, but listeners attached with document.attachEvent are not triggered.

Comment: @Eric: thought as much. That's a bummer man.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh Too bad. If you make your comment into an answer I'll be glad to accept it. Any reason behind the fact that 'readystatechange' and 'load' behave differently?

Comment: @Eric you should also probably attach to the `document.body.attachEvent()` instead of just `document.attachEvent()`

Comment: @gnarf probably... I'm looking into it, just checking if I assumed incorrectly that document.attachEvent('onload', something) should ever fire

Comment: @gnarf: I don't believe handlers attached to `document.body.attachEvent('onload', ...)` fire when the page loads normally anyway. IE forces you to attach either via `<body onload="..."`, `window.onload = ...`, or `window.attachEvent('onload', ...)`.

Comment: but apparently window's onload and document.body's onload are the same?  *shrug* just a thought...

Comment: @gnarf: Nope. `<body onload="..."` is the only way to map to the window's `onload` event AFAIK. `document.body.attachEvent('onload', ...)` is just ignored.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh That's the conclusion I just reached by running a couple of new tests: listeners for the 'onload' event are only fired in IE when attached through window.attachEvent, not document.attachEvent nor document.body.attachEvent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197055%28VS.85%29.aspx), there's no `onload` event for `document`.

You want either `window.onload` or `document.body.onload`. These are identical in IE: for historical reasons, `<body onload="...">` actually sets `window.onload`, so MS decided to make `document.body.onload` an alias of `window.onload`.

The problem with this is - as Eric mentioned in the comments - that there doesn't seem to be a way to manually fire window events, which means that there might not be a solution for Eric's problem.

Comment: @Christoph: good point, already mentioned by Crescent Fresh: I should fire the event on document.body instead. Interesting comment on window.onload but not so helpful since window has no fireEvent method.

Comment: @Christoph thanks for editing your answer. I'll accept it as a conclusion to this interesting discussion.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, it appears that IE overrides the `onload` property of `window` with an empty object after the DOM is loaded. At least that is the case when you try to access it from within any event handler of a DOM element...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test by Josh</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        alert("Test");
      }
      alert(typeof window.onload);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 onclick="alert(typeof window.onload);">Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this situation, you'll see that window.onload is recognized as a function initially, then you see the "Test" alert.  When you click on the heading, you'll see that window.onload is now an `object`.  I tried iterating through the properties of the object, but it's empty. This is not cool.

One lame workaround is to grab the function in the accessible scope and assign it to a different property that you can fire at your convenience...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test by Josh</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        alert("Test");
      }         
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 onclick="window.onloadfix()">Test</h1>
    <!-- Could potentially be injected via server-side include if needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onloadfix = function() {
        window.onload();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't think of any other way to address this issue right now.

Comment: @Josh Stodola interesting... I discovered today that document.attachEvent is not a function in IE: you can call it of course, but (typeof document.attachEvent) returns "object" and both document.attachEvent.call and document.attachEvent.apply are undefined... this browser will never stop to surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

The load event will fire when the document (including external resources such as images) has fully loaded, and not before.

What results are you getting from your attempts to fire `readystatechange`? Does the `readyState` value actually change at all? Whether or not, that's not of much use either: either you fire the event with a `readyState` that hasn't changed, or you do so with a `readyState` that isn't a valid reflection of the state of the document.

Comment: @NickFitz Thanks for the answer. I am not trying to change the value of document.readyState, which remains 'complete' before (because I have a wait until readyState becomes 'complete') and after my test. Please keep in mind that this code is written for unit tests.

Comment: @NickFitz: Eric is just trying to simulate the real-world `load` event for local unit tests.

Comment: If it's for a unit test then you shouldn't need to fire any events at all. Simply create a mock event object with known values and call the event handler directly, then check that it produced the correct results for those values. Otherwise it's not a unit test, it's an integration test: you are testing how the code integrates with the browser's internal event handling mechanisms.

Comment: @NickFitz except I am not unit-testing the event handlers :) I am writing unit tests for a method that replaces and filters the addEventListener and attachEvent on window and document.