# Silverlight Control Caching in IE

Tags: javascript, silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-5.0

Hi We have a silverlight control hosted in a hidden div (and height 0px) which is then shown within a jquery dialog when a user clicks a button the page
The initial showing of the dialog calls the onLoad param and initialises the silverlight control correctly. However the user has the option to close the dialog and hide the silverlight control.

The user can then show this dialog again (without reloading a page), however, in IE the onLoad param is not fired and consequently our silverlight control is not initialised correctly as we are handling hardware within it. In Chrome, however, the onLoad param is fired everytime the jquery dialog is shown

Two very different behaviours. I cant remove the the hidden div from the dom as it might be needed again

Is there a solution to forcibly reload the silverlight control so that the param onLoad is fired everytime the control is displayed with the jquery dialog?

TIA
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got an overall idea.  Raising onLoad is definitely not good.
but let me suggest solution above.

Register communication objects(aka functions) in JS and silverlight as well. So you will be able to communicate JS -> Silverlight

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateSilverlight() {
        // call silverlight control method
        var control = document.getElementById("silverlightControl");
        control.Content.Page.SomeMethod("someData');
    } 
</script>
```

Annotate class like this:

```
 [ScriptableType]
    public partial class SomePage: UserControl
    {
```

Annotate appropriate method inside SomePage

```
  [ScriptableMember]
        public void SomeMethod(string somedata)
        {
            var data = somedata;
        }
```

where data is your re-init params...

hope that helps

Comment: Yeah fairly complicated setup. but manage to find an answer I'll add the it below

Comment: From Tech perceptive it's fine. It's just another way how it can be done and will work for sure. 

Also you might find that conversation usefull  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874866/how-to-fire-onload-event-on-document-in-ie about onLoad

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for opening dialog that contained the silverlight control

```
$('#ReadCard').on('click', function (e) {

    $('#silverlightControlHost').height('300');

    e.preventDefault();

    //show the read card dialog
    $("#readCardDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 390,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Close': function () {
                Call_SL_OnBeforeUnload();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On loading the silverlight control there is a method call to SilverlightInitialisation:

```
    function onSilverlightLoad(sender, eventargs) {
    .....
    pluginElem.Content.SR_SMT.SilverlightInitialisation(inputArray);
     }
```

Which was called by the optional silverlight paramater:

```
  <param name="onload" value="onSilverlightLoad" />
```

This started the hardware that the silverlight control was talking to.

When the dialog was closed the method is called to stop the hardware:

```
Call_SL_OnBeforeUnload();
```

However when the dialog is shown again in IE the SilverlightInitialisation method is never called unless the user would refresh the page.

A work around was to alter the method (OnLoad)  to the silverlight control that was always called when the dialog was opened but that checked a flag (hasLoaded) to see if it loaded previously:

Silverlight

```
[ScriptableMember]
    public string OnLoad()
    {
        string retVal = G4T.SilverlightBadge.Resources.ResourcesFile.Present_Card;

        if (_badgeReadCtrl != null && hasLoaded)
        {
            if (!_badgeReadCtrl.Initialise())
            {
                retVal = "Failed to initialise reader device";
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

The OnFirstLoad method was added which was called when the silverlight control first loaded  and set the flag accordingly

```
[ScriptableMember]
    public string OnFirstLoad()
    {
        string retVal = G4T.SilverlightBadge.Resources.ResourcesFile.Present_Card;

        if (_badgeReadCtrl != null)
        {
            if (!_badgeReadCtrl.Initialise())
            {
                retVal = "Failed to initialise reader device";
            }
        }
        hasLoaded = true;
        return retVal;
    }
```

Javascript

```
 open: function (event, ui) {
            try {
                var plugin = document.getElementById('SilverlightMainControl');
                if (plugin) {
                    plugin.Content.SR_SMT.OnLoad();
                }
            }
            catch(e){}
        },
```

Like I said above this always worked in Chrome without the modifications but in IE the initialisation is never called more than once

Hope all this makes sense  - but i had to document it for future ref